# Display New WordPress Post Without Reloading Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to load a new post in wordpress without reloading the entire page. I am not sure where to start with this. I am new to AJAX and JavaScript. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to AJAX and javascript, I would start by looking into an AJAX / JavaScript library.  Here are a few to look at:

- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [ASP.Net AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) (plus the [AJAXControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/))

Each of these have their own methods of making ajax calls.  Start by looking into those methods, and come back to this site when you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XML-RPC Service](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) ([Documentation Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp)) that WordPress supports for posting, editing, and other functionality in combination with one of the AJAX solutions, such as jQuery, that Gabriel mentioned.

If the functionality you want is not supported in WordPress' XML-RPC service, it also supports the [Blogger API](http://www.blogger.com/developers/api/), [metaWeblog API](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi), and the [Movable Type API](http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/movable_type_api/).